# godep doesnt install required packages

Tags: docker, go, godeps

I'm trying to run the application (written in Go) inside docker. To install dependencies I'm using godep. When executing godep inside docker, following error is received

```
 docker run -ti --rm -v $PWD:/go/src/app -p3000:3000 golang bash 
 root@7c491d184712:/go/src/app# go get github.com/tools/godep 
 root@7c491d184712:/go/src/reno# godep save 
 godep: Package (github.com/Shopify/sarama) not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Godep needs you to have local copies of the dependencies you want to vendor. You should run `go get` before running `godep save`. Additionally, assuming you have sub-packages in your app folder, you should run `godep save ./...`.

Godep's readme: https://github.com/tools/godep#how-to-use-godep-with-a-new-project

Comment: Ok. How to handle the dependencies in production?

Comment: There are two ways to handle dependencies in production. Option 1 is to commit the `vendor` in your repo, this way you can `go build` on your production systems without worrying about dependencies. Option 2 is to omit the `vendor` directory, and use `godep restore` to installed the vendored packages. Not that option 2 won't work if you have dependencies in private repositories.